# In Mongoose findOneAndUpdate, how can I make my post request work?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi all so I am trying to make a post request that increments a value if it already exists and if not it should create a new item.

```
router.post('/', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { name, price, image } = req.body;
    var query = { name },
      update = { $inc: { count: 1 } },
      options = { upsert: true, new: true,};
    await CartItem.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, function (
      err,
      data
    ) {
      if (err) {
        const newItem = new CartItem({
          user: req.user.id,
          name: name,
          price: price,
          image: image,
        });
        const item = newItem.save();
        res.json(item);
      } else {
        res.json(data);
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const CartItemSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user',
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  count: {
    type: Number,
  },
  image: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

module.exports = CartItem = mongoose.model('cartItem', CartItemSchema);
```

So there are two problems here that I cannot wrap my head around(Pretty new with MongoDb, did do my research).

1. I can get the count to increment, but it increments with 2 or even more instead of 1. (I know other users also experienced this)
2. If the item is already in the cart(name matches) I want a new item to be added which does happen, but it only adds the name, count and Id. I want it to add the user, name, price and image.

Would appreciate some assistance.

Answer (score 0):

you should create your document with a default value equals to 0.

define count at your schema like the following:

```
count: {
  type: Number,
  default: 0
}
```

then use `{ $inc: { <field1>: <amount1>, <field2>: <amount2>, ... } }`.

link to docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I have tried this. Count still increments with 2